# my php code does not work with session_start and mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

my code is here

```
<?php 
// This section processes submissions from the login form.
// Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//connect to database
require ('mysqli_connect.php');
// Validate the email address:
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['email']);

} else {
$e = FALSE;
    echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your email address.</p>';
}
// Validate the password:
if (!empty($_POST['psword'])) {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['psword']);

} else {
$p = FALSE;
    echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your password.</p>';
}

if ($e && $p){//if no problems
// Retrieve the user_id, first_name and user_level for that     email/password combination:

    $q = "SELECT user_id, fname, user_level FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND psword=SHA1('$p'))";

    $result = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); 
    // Check the result:
    if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {//The user input matched the     database rcoord
    // Start the session, fetch the record and insert the three values    in an array
    session_start();

    //echo '<pre>';

    //print_r($_SESSION);
    //echo '</pre>';
    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //echo '<br>33333333333333333333333333333333333<br>';
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($_SESSION);
    //echo '</pre>';
   $_SESSION['user_level'] = (int) $_SESSION['user_level']; // Changes the 1 or 2 user level to an integer.
   $url = ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 1) ? 'admin-page.php' : 'members-   page.php'; // Ternary operation to set the URL
   header('Location: ' . $url); // Makes the actual page jump. Keep in mind that $url is a relative path.
 exit(); // Cancels the rest of the script.
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($dbcon);
//ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
} else { // No match was made.
echo '<p class="error">The email address and password entered do not match our records.<br>Perhaps you need to register, click the Register button on the header menu</p>';
}
} else { // If there was a problem.
    echo '<p class="error">Please try again.</p>';
}
mysqli_close($dbcon);
} // End of SUBMIT conditional.
?>
```

and my form is:

```
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
<p><label class="label" for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" > </p>
<br>
<p><label class="label" for="psword">Password:</label>
<input id="psword" type="password" name="psword" size="12"     maxlength="12" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['psword'])) echo $_POST['psword']; ?>" ><span>&nbsp;Between 8 and 12 characters.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
 </form><br>
```

why this code does not log to the admin-page.php or members-page.php
althogh i enter email and pass correctly.
result of this code pointed to the login page!

Comment: please first format your code and show what's the error is coming and remember **session_start();** should be on the top in your code.

Comment: 1. Check that the query actually returns any results. 2. Remove error-suprsessions (`@` in front of functions). 3. Do proper error-checks and handling.